# DAO (Dessign Pattern) with User restrictions

Tags: java, design-patterns, dao

I was wondering if there is a way of performing the next:

I have 2 kinds of user (`UserA`, `UserB`). A class `Student` and a class `Classroom`.

`UserB` has a `List<Classroom> Classrooms;`.

`UserA` can save a `Student` into any `Classroom`.

`UserB` can save a `Student` into a `Classroom` he ownes.

So, the `StudentDAO` has differents methods for each kind of user.

How can I do that? I think, the best way is:

In the constructor of the users, I instantiate a `StudentDAO` with the implementation that feets the user. Is that correct?

What if `ClassroomDAO` has the method `getAll();`. `UserA` will see every `Classroom`. But `UserB` will see all the `Classroom` that he ownes. But this method will be the same that `UserB.getClassrooms();`. 2 methods would do the same.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You should not mix the data model and user roles. Even the sentence

> UserB *has* a List Classrooms

should be reformulated as

> UserB *can access* a List Classrooms

to avoid this confusion.

In your data model, you should have *one single* `Student`, not `StudentforUserA` and `StudentForUserB`. And very probably you should also have *one single* `User` with its role(s) as attributes. It's more than probable that you will have later more user roles and your class hierarchy would grow up uncontrollably.

You should also have *one single* DAO for each object type (`Student`, `Classroom`). DAO generally should be client-unaware. Unless your user type is somehow connected with your access rights control mechanism - but then you know who is logged in and your DAO return data or an exception according to the current user's rights.

It's perfectly OK to have access methods which throw an exception if you do not have sufficient access rights.

Now it depends on what UserA and UserB are:

1. User roles - based on something from the database, not known in design time. Then the DAO should throw an exception when trying to read the unwanted data and you should handle the exception higher so the user is politely informed that he is not authorized.
2. Different actors - something you already know in design time. Then simply do not call the unwanted methods.

Comment: So, you are telling me that the restrictions should be written in the View of the MVC?

Comment: Not at all! It depends what exactly you mean by UserA and UserB, I implicitly understand it as user roles, which you do not know in the design time. In this case the MODEL should return only such data to which the role has access rights.

Comment: However, if you *do* know in design time who is using the Student instance, simply do not call the unwanted method(s) and that's all.